# How can I change Android spinner DatePicker text appearance?

Tags: android, xml, android-datepicker

It's style of my DatePicker:

```xml
<style name="AppDatePicker">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?textAppearanceLabelSmall</item> <!-- This effects nothing. -->
    <item name="android:colorControlNormal">?colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

It's my DatePicker:

```xml
<DatePicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    android:datePickerMode="spinner"
    android:spinnersShown="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppDatePicker" />
```

How can I change spinner DatePicker's text appearance ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow xml attrs here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker#summary

We have:

```xml
android:dayOfWeekTextAppearance
android:headerMonthTextAppearance
... and more
```

> These attrs are deprecated from sdk 28

Other solution, create theme for date picker and set `CalendarStyle`

```xml
<style name="MyDatePicker" parent="....">
        <item name="android:calendarViewStyle">@style/MyCalendar</item>

<!-- For spinner -->
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/...</item>
<item name="fontFamily">...</item>
<item name="android:textSize">...</item>

</style>

<style name="MyCalendar" parent="...">
   <item name="android:dateTextAppearance">Your text appearance</item>
</style>
```

use it

```
 <DatePicker
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/MyDatePicker" .../>
```

Comment: None of these affect. @dinhlam

Comment: Ah sorry I have checked and these attrs are deprecated from android sdk 26. Let check my editted answer.

Comment: Sorry, that did not work either.

Comment: You are using spinner, I have added solution for it.